# Set video playback rate on Netflix from the google chrome browser console

Tags: javascript, html5-video, google-chrome-devtools, netflix, google-chrome-console

Netflix doesn't provide control for the playback rate in its user interface.

What should I put in the google chrome console to set the playback rate that I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the video to go twice as fast you set it to

`document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 2`

If you want half the speed you set it to

`document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 0.5`

If you want the normal speed back you set it to

`document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1`

You can add this as a bookmark url so you don't need to open the console anymore, just click on the bookmark to change the speed :

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 2}())
```

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 0.5}())
```

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1}())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2`

also works!